# How to write a function to change on mouseover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, user-interface

I have a user interface with some buttons and when I hover over them I want them to change appearance. I have this implemented and it works, but I was wondering how I could maybe write this as a JQuery function in a separate JS file so my html is a bit more cleaned up. This is what I have that does this in my html file.

```
<input class= "center-block" type="image" id="open" style= "width: 75%; height: auto" src="/msViz/UserInterface/Slices/Untoggled/Open.png" onmouseover="$(this).attr('src','/msViz/UserInterface/Slices/Toggled/Open_Toggle.png')" onmouseout="$(this).attr('src','/msViz/UserInterface/Slices/Untoggled/Open.png')"/><br>
<input class= "center-block" type="image" id="save" style= "width: 75%; height: auto" src="/msViz/UserInterface/Slices/Untoggled/Save.png" onmouseover="$(this).attr('src','/msViz/UserInterface/Slices/Toggled/Save_Toggle.png')" onmouseout="$(this).attr('src','/msViz/UserInterface/Slices/Untoggled/Save.png')"/><br>
<input class= "center-block" type="image" id="import" style= "width: 75%; height: auto" src="/msViz/UserInterface/Slices/Untoggled/Import.png" onmouseover="$(this).attr('src','/msViz/UserInterface/Slices/Toggled/Import_Toggle.png')" onmouseout="$(this).attr('src','/msViz/UserInterface/Slices/Untoggled/Import.png')"/><br>
<input class= "center-block" type="image" id="next" style= "width: 75%; height: auto" src="/msViz/UserInterface/Slices/Untoggled/Next.png" onmouseover="$(this).attr('src','/msViz/UserInterface/Slices/Toggled/Next_Toggle.png')" onmouseout="$(this).attr('src','/msViz/UserInterface/Slices/Untoggled/Next.png')"/><br>
<input class= "center-block" type="image" id="edit" style= "width: 75%; height: auto" src="/msViz/UserInterface/Slices/Untoggled/Edit.png" onmouseover="$(this).attr('src','/msViz/UserInterface/Slices/Toggled/Edit_Toggle.png')" onmouseout="$(this).attr('src','/msViz/UserInterface/Slices/Untoggled/Edit.png')"/><br>
<input class= "center-block" type="image" id="mode" style= "width: 75%; height: auto" src="/msViz/UserInterface/Slices/Untoggled/Mode.png" onmouseover="$(this).attr('src','/msViz/UserInterface/Slices/Toggled/Mode_Toggle.png')" onmouseout="$(this).attr('src','/msViz/UserInterface/Slices/Untoggled/Mode.png')"/><br>
<input class= "center-block" type="image" id="clear" style= "width: 75%; height: auto" src="/msViz/UserInterface/Slices/Untoggled/Clear.png" onmouseover="$(this).attr('src','/msViz/UserInterface/Slices/Toggled/Clear_Toggle.png')" onmouseout="$(this).attr('src','/msViz/UserInterface/Slices/Untoggled/Clear.png')"/><br>
<input class= "center-block" type="image" id="data" style= "width: 75%; height: auto" src="/msViz/UserInterface/Slices/Untoggled/Data.png" onmouseover="$(this).attr('src','/msViz/UserInterface/Slices/Toggled/Data_Toggle.png')" onmouseout="$(this).attr('src','/msViz/UserInterface/Slices/Untoggled/Data.png')"/><br>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `css` `background-image` , `:hover` `.addClass()` , `.removeClass()` , `setTimeout()` to cache images for `:hover` toggle

```js
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
inputs[0].className = "hover";
setTimeout(
  function() {
    inputs[0].className = "";
  }
)
```

```css
input {
  width:75%;
  height:auto;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/302/302/nature);
}
input:hover,
input.hover {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/302/302/cats);
}
```

```html
<input class="center-block" type="image" id="open" />
<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two variants to do that:

1.Only with CSS:

```
<input class= "center-block" type="text" id="open" />

input#open { background: url('/msViz/UserInterface/Slices/Untoggled/Open.png') no-repeat 0 0; }
input#open:hover { background: url('/msViz/UserInterface/Slices/Toggled/Open_Toggle.png') no-repeat 0 0; }
```

2.With jQuery (firstly include the jQuery library in your document):

```
<input class= "center-block" type="image" id="open" style= "width: 75%; height: auto" src="/msViz/UserInterface/Slices/Untoggled/Open.png" />

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#open').hover(function(){
        $(this).attr('src', '/msViz/UserInterface/Slices/Toggled/Open_Toggle.png');
    }, function(){
        $(this).attr('src', '/msViz/UserInterface/Slices/Untoggled/Open.png');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can write this in a separate javascript file. Include the following in your javascript file:

```
$("#open").mouseover(function() { 
    $(this).attr("src", "..../Open_Toggle.png"); 
});
$("#open").mouseout(function() {
    $(this).attr("src", "..../Open.png");
});
```

But since you have lot of buttons, this is quite more verbose than I would want. Instead, I would assign a class to each of these `input` elements like so:

```
<input class="hoverable center-block" ... />
```

And then write just one block like this (I have not verified this code, but you get the idea):

```
$(".hoverable").mouseover(function() {
    var existingSrc = $(this).attr("src");
    $(this).attr("src", existingSrc.substring(0, existingSrc.length - 4) + "-Toggle.png";
});
$(".hoverable").mouseout(function() {
    var existingSrc = $(this).attr("src");
    $(this).attr("src", existingSrc.replace("-Toggle", ""));
});
```